# How to count all the possible subsets of a list greater than equal to c

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

How i can find all the subsets of a list . suppose i have a `list [1,2,3,4]` and c=5 ,

so the subsest will be `{3,2}` ,  and `{4,1}`

i don't want to consider an element twice so `{1,2,3}` will not be consider

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use dfs approve to compute all subsets.
In dfs function when index is equal to len(nums), we can assume that subset is found.

Now we first compute sum of subset and will check if this is equal to target, if not we will not add it in our output result.

If this equal, then we will verify, if all items of curr are not visited. If all are not visited, then we will add it in output list.

```
class Solution:
    
    def dfs(self, nums, index, curr, res):
        if index == len(nums):
            if sum(curr) != self.target:
                return
            flag = 0
            for item in curr:
                if self.visited[nums.index(item)]:
                    flag = 1
                    break
            if flag == 0:
                for item in curr:
                    self.visited[nums.index(item)] = True
                res.append(curr[:])
            return
        curr.append(nums[index])
        self.dfs(nums, index + 1, curr, res)
        curr.pop()
        self.dfs(nums, index + 1, curr, res)
        return
    
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int], target) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        curr = []
        self.target = target
        self.visited = [False] * len(nums)
        self.dfs(nums, 0, curr, res)
        return res
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `itertools.combinations` with a `list` comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [i for n in range(len(lst) + 1) for i in combinations(lst, n) if sum(set(i)) == 5]
[(1, 4), (2, 3)]
>>>
```

Comment: Its not necessary to have a fix subset length .

Comment: @Akashnitter Edited my answer, now it doesn't have a fixed subset length, please upvote and accept if it works

Comment: @U11-Forward I guess, you are missing this line in question
"i don't want to consider an element twice so {1,2,3} will not be consider"

Comment: Thanks but your code is considering elements twice in case of sum(i)>= 5

Comment: @Akashnitter No it doesn't now, I changes it, I used `set`, please see the most recent edit

Comment: @U11-Forward in case of lst [1,2,3,4] and sum(set(i)) >= k , its giving output like [(1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)] please check once

Comment: @Akashnitter It should work, copy the whole thing

Comment: @U11-Forward in case of > its showing Multiple occurrences of an element

Comment: @Akashnitter No it shouldn't